# How do I set the working directory of a batch script to where the shortcut is invoked?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a simple batch script that copies the contents of `./source` to a destination specified as an argument. Once the files in `./source` are copied to the destination, they are moved to `./archive`.

```
script.cmd "\\web01\www\accounting\assets" "otherArgs"
```

This script is going to be used to in several areas, but instead of having discrete copies of the script in each area it is being used, I want to utilize shortcuts(.lnk) to point back to one copy of the script, so that if changes are made everyone using it is using the most up-to-date version.

The folder structure would look something like this:

```
company
|
+-- script.cmd
|
+-- accounting
|  |
|  +-- archive
|  |   |
|  |   \-- oldFile
|  |
|  +-- source
|  |   |
|  |   \-- newFile
|  |
|  \-- script.lnk -> ..\script.cmd
|
+-- hr
|  |
|  +-- archive
|  |   |
|  |   \-- oldFile
|  |
|  +-- source
|  |   |
|  |   \-- newFile
|  |
|  \-- script.lnk -> ..\script.cmd
|
+-- sales
|  |
|  +-- archive
|  |   |
|  |   \-- oldFile
|  |
|  +-- source
|  |   |
|  |   \-- newFile
|  |
|  \-- script.lnk -> ..\script.cmd
|
...
```

Currently, the script is not using the correct archive and source directories. It is trying to look for the directories at the top level, not in the subdirectories. Is there a variable like `%~dp0` or `%cd%` that would have the path where the shortcut resides? Or is there a way I can pass it in as an argument without using an absolute path? Such as

```
script.cmd "\\web01\www\accounting\assets" "%cd%" "otherArgs"
```

Comment: Is the "Start In" field of the shortcut blank?

Comment: Instead of a .lnk file you could make it a symbolic link (type `mklink /?` for help). Then the batch file will think it is located wherever the symbolic link is placed, but you'll be able to change the contents centrally by changing the "real" batch file.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I tried to create the symlnk as `company\accounting\test.cmd <<==>> company\script.cmd`, but I get the error message "The system cannot open the device or file specified." I saw that this can be caused by not having the `.bat` or `.cmd` extension, but I tried with both of those file extensions to no avail.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I tried removing that from the .lnk, but it still uses the path to the original batch file as the working directory.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou - This may not work if multiple physical file systems are involved.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I've tried and succeeded in creating a symbolic link on the C:\ hard drive that refers to an R: TrueCrypt volume (so very different file systems).

Comment: @RobertEllegate what exact command line did you use to create the symbolic link? It ought to work. Preferably you should use full absolute paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alias script:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@cd %~dp0
call %path_to_script%\script.cmd %*
```

Put one of those in each of your directories. No shortcuts required.